# xhr.upload.onprogress doesn't work

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest-level2

Everything in the following code will work, except it will never fire the xhr.upload.onprogress event.

```
$(function(){

    var xhr;

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("myFile", document.getElementById("myFileField").files[0]);
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "./test.php", true);
        xhr.send(formData);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);              
            }
        }

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
           // it will never come inside here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you must define your handlers before the calls to open.

Comment: Someone create the answer so I can accept it please. @VoidMain was correct.

Comment: @user1534664 xhr.upload.onprogress is working fine with IE but doesn't work with chrome and FF. Have you got any solution?  Please do share your comments

Comment: @Sankar2.0 If you share your code I can have a look at it, but as it is right now I don't have enough information to conclude what your problem is. Make sure you use xhr.open() and xhr.send() after you declare your listeners, as that was my issue here.

Comment: you are correct! we set all the properties and open() before send(). that works for me. Great. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should create the listeners before opening the connection, like this:

```
$(function(){

    var xhr;

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("myFile", document.getElementById("myFileField").files[0]);
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);              
            }
        }

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
           // it will never come inside here
        }

        xhr.open("POST", "./test.php", true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can open connection before handlers, but send need to be after.

Comment: Hi, I have similar code like this but not working on mobile app.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581293/upload-using-xmlhttprequest-not-working-on-mobile

Is xhr not working on react js?